# I want cumulative of production qty which I saved in key value 'pqty' in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want cumulative of production qty in key 'pqty' property:

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
 DatabaseReference valuesRef = rootRef.child("alldata").child("pqty");
 ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    int sum = o;
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        int value = ds.getValue(Integer.class);
        sum = sum + value;

    }
    textview15.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};

    valuesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

I tried this and got output as 0. But I want output as 750.

I'm using sketch ware.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are storing the "pqty" property in your database as a String and **not** as a number, which in my opinion is a really bad idea. If your data type is a number, then you should store it like that. Now, to get the desired sum, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference alldataRef = rootRef.child("alldata");
alldataRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String pqty = ds.child("pqty").getValue(String.class);
                sum += Integer.parseInt(pqty);
            }
            Log.d("TAG", "sum= " + sum);
            textview15.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

According to your screenshot, the result in your logcat will be:

```
sum= 750
```

Things to notice:

- There's no need for any ".child("pqty")" call in your "valuesRef" reference whatsoever, because you need to loop through the "DataSnapshot" object using a call to ".getChildren()" method and then get the value of "pqty" property.
- To be able to sum those values, you need to parse that String object into a number using [Integer.parseInt(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method.
- There is no way you can get a String value from the database using ".getValue(Integer.class)", as it will always yield an Exception. You need to get it as it's actually stored.

Comment: Hi bro, how to save in number type ? Thanks bro

Comment: Instead of saving it as a String using .child("pqty").setValue("100"), use .child("pqty").setValue(100). Meaning that 100 is a number, without quotes. If you have a model class, simply change the type of the property from String to long. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I'm using sketch ware. There . Map : savedata put key pqty value textview edittext get text..... Firebase DB :alldata push value map savedata

Comment: If it's about a Map, then use map.put("pqty", 100), no quotes.

Comment: Bro I found something in app it show code bro. ........Savedata.put("pqty", edittext,getText().to string ()); .. ......can I change that last string to Integer () ???

Comment: As in my answer, using Integer.parseInt(edit text.getText().toString()). Does it work now?

Comment: I tried bro It showing more error bro.. that's why I'm to Change number type...........  Savedata.put("pqty", edittext4.getText().value of()); this I got Google still showing errors

Comment: Finally worked bro.. but half your tips and another half program given by another person . I like to thank both of bro.. he deleted his code.. I don't know why

Comment: Done ✅ bro ... Thanks a lot bro